# 500 Internal Server Error - When I login to the application with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring MVC and I'm trying to login to an application in a PRE environment, despite entering the correct user and password I throw the following error:

[image: Error 500 - Internal Server Error]

Viewing the log of the application the last one that is visualized is an access to a DAO, and aparantemente never ends to solve the query.
And the last thing I can say is that if we clean the chrome cache, the application is logged without problems.

Could it be that the j_query_spring_security_check is causing a problem?
Please help.

Comment: please to add you code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, it was a problem that had to be solved as quickly as possible. Sorry for not adding the code, finally the problem was that the application had a load balancer with 2 nodes, and one of the nodes always fails.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not adding the code, finally the problem was that the application had a load balancer with 2 nodes, and one of the nodes always fails :/
Regards.